# How I redirect dynamic url with query string in php?

Tags: php

I  need to redirect dynamic URL like this "https://test.com?user=abc@gmail.com" to "https://test.com"

Comment: `<?php header("location: https://test.com"); ?>` ???

Comment: And how are you getting this url? Is this storted in a variable?

Comment: But I think you need user query string in the next page on same URL. right ? If yes then you just need to post the variable with corresponding value.

Comment: I am getting abc@gmail.com using session from database i make a query string  https://test.com?user=abc@gmail.com when i reffer this  to https://test.com?user=abc@gmail.com any of new user when new user enter this url on browser side it shoud redirect to  https://test.com.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this URL is coming dynamically with a query string. And you want to remove the query string portion and redirect to this modified URL.

Let's assume the dynamic URL is stored in a variable $url.

Try this:

```
$url = "https://test.com?user=abc@gmail.com";
$modified_url = strstr($url, "?", true); // Remove the query string, which results in https://test.com

header("location:".$modified_url);  // Redirect to the modified URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dynamic part in a variable and use the `header()` function to redirect your user.

```
$dynamicPart = "someguy@somedomain.com";
header("Location: https://test.com/index.php?username=".$dynamicPart);
exit;
```